# Sea creatures (not fish) that have the suffix 'fish'?

Tags: word-request

I think of two sea creatures of which their names end with the suffix '**fish**': Cuttle**fish**, shell-**fish**, although by definition they aren't real fish.

Are there more names of sea creatures (which aren't real fish) that have the suffix '**fish**'?

Comment: Animal nomenclature is often inaccurate. Honey Badgers aren't badgers. Bearcats are neither bears nor cats. Electric Eels aren't eels. etc etc etc

Comment: The word is shellfish, no hyphen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a few more examples:  starfish and jellyfish, are sea creatures. Crayfish/crawfish are freshwater creatures. Silverfish are land creatures. They are certainly not "fish" in the biological sense. "Blackfish" is an old name for pilot whales, also not a fish.

Strictly speaking, lungfish are more closely related to us than to other fish and  "hagfish" are no more closely related to other fish than we are, and so might not be considered "real" fish by some people.

(Just for fun here is a family tree of the things called "fish", with humans for comparison)

```
Jellyfish---------------------------|
                                    |
Crayfish----------------|           |
                        |---|       |------
Silverfish--------------|   |       |
                            |---|   |
Cuttlefish------------------|   |   |
                                |---|
Starfish--------------------|   |
                            |---|
Hagfish-----------------|   |
                        |---|
(real) Fish---------|   |
                    |---|
Lungfish--------|   |
                |---|
Blackfish --|   |
            |---|
Humans------|
```

Comment: Cladistically, there is, famously, "no such thing as a fish".

Comment: Indeed, nor "reptiles" nor "apes" nor "dinosaurs" nor many of the words that we use all the time.  However introducing 
Actinopterygii  would seem to be more confusing than enlightening.

Comment: @JamesK Apes and dinosaurs do exist cladistically, all it requires you to say is "birds are dinosaurs" and "humans are apes", which are both reasonable statements. On the other hand "humans are fish" and "birds are reptiles" are less reasonable statements, hence why fish and reptiles don't exist and we have the words vertebrate and sauropsid to use instead.

Comment: I would say hagfish and lungfish are real fish.

Comment: We don't have to use the word "vertebrate".  The word "reptile" (and the words "fish", "ape" and "dinosaur") all have well understood meanings outside of their cladistic definition. So you've got to decide, are you going to use "clades" (and so lungfish are in the clade that includes humans, not the clade that includes salmon), in which case you aren't going to use a word like "fish" at all. or are you going to use "normal English", in which case you'd better get used to "ape" meaning "non-human simian".

Answer (score 1):

True fishes belong to the phylum pisces. Fishes that are not actually fishes include:

- Jellyfish - Coelenterate
- Silverfish - Insect
- Hagfish - Cyclostome
- Starfish - Echinoderm
- Cuttlefish - Mollusk
- Devilfish - Mollusk
- Crayfish - Crustacean

Answer (score -2):

There are many names ending in "fish". Take your pick. For example see the following [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fish_common_names). Everything fron "African glass catfish" to "Zebra turkeyfish".

Comment: Note this is a list of actual fish and misses many non-fish sea creatures like starfish, shellfish, jellyfish, etc.